# Failed to load certain images react native listview

Tags: android, listview, azure, react-native

In the application that I am creating I am using a listview which uses a Gamecard component. Inside this component we are using the Image component which gets images from an Azure blob storage. This works for most of the times but there are certain cases that this doesn't work. 
When this occurs the onError event gets triggered but in the event I don't get any error returned so investigating the problem is pretty hard.

I am catching it like follows:

```
 source={{uri: config.storage.endpoint + this.state.game._id + "/" + this.state.game._id + '-compr'}}
                onError={(err) => {
                    console.log('Something happened!')
                }}
```

I have tried reading the `err` object but nothing usefull coming out of this object.
The images are relatively small (with size and MB) so I am lost on where to search next.

Hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: Does `console.log(err.nativeEvent.error)` give you what you're wanting? As per the doc `onError - Invoked on load error with {nativeEvent: {error}}.`

Comment: Good suggestion but when I do that I get `undefined` returned. Maybe any other way to get a valid error returned?